# keep radio button selected across postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, radiobuttonlist

I have a gridview with radio buttons to select a single row.
The gridview is populated from a SQL DB according to a value selected from a drop down list.
What I want to do is keep the selected radio button when the user moves to a different category, so if he wants to move back via the DDL the value he selected previously is still selected.

What is the best way to do this?
The application will have users and I have read sessions could help me with this but I have no idea how it works!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Across postback, I don't think this makes sense, unless you want to save the selection to database upon selecting a new category from the drop down list

Comment: Every time you move through the drop down list you populate your gridview with data from SQL ?

Comment: @SirajMansour Yes every time the user selects a different category from the drop down list the gridview is repopulated from SQL

Comment: @Hassan I save the selected values in hidden fields to allow the user to move back through the categories and change their selection, and I have a submit button to commit the data to my database all at once at the end. By across postbacks I mean when the user selects a different category and then later returns to the same one the radio button is not selected anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure really why you'd want to do it this way but you'd then save it in session this way:

```
String selectedValue = rblYourRadioButtons.SelectedValue;
Session["SelectedRadioButtonValue"] = selectedValue;
```

Then, on postback or whenever, on the Item Databound of the gridview you check if the current row Id matches the value stored in the session, if it does then select that value in the radiobutton list.

Personally I'd store the value in the DB rather than session.

Comment: I store the value in the DB when the user finishes, the reason I want to do it like this is to allow the user to change his vote before I commit to the DB. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: ok, that's fine, I think my answer should work for you in that case.